# storing results of foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following php script:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  global $db;
  $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
  if ($cart) {
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
    }

    $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
    $total=0;
    echo 'you have following books';
    echo '</br>';
    $output[] = '<table>';

    foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE bcode ='$id'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);
      $row = $result->fetch();
      extract($row);
      $output[] = '<tr>';

      $a = $output[] = '<td>  '.$bname.'</td>';
      $output[] = '<td>'.$price.'rs.</td>';
      $output[] = '<td>*'.$qty.'</td>';
      '</br>';
      $output[] = '<td>Rs.'.($price * $qty).'</td>';
      $total += $price * $qty;
      $output[] = '</tr>';
    }

    $output[] = '</table>';
    $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>Rs.'.$total.'</strong></p>';

    $output[] = '</form>';
  } else {
    $output[] = '<p>You shopping cart is empty.</p>';
  }


?>
```

Is there a way to store results of the `foreach` loop in variables? .i.e $a will contain book name, but if there are two books the value of $a gets overwritten by the next book?

Comment: you can define a variable e.g. $bookName and set it's value to the result of the sql query, then each time the loop runs it will override $bookName with the new name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a= $output[] = '<td>  '.$bname.'</td>';
```

You're re-intialising `$a` in every iteration of the loop.

All you need to do is set it right at the end of the function, with, say, an implode on `$output`

```
$a = implode ('\n', $output);
```

Or, if you don't want the whole output, just use it as an array:

```
$a[] = $output[] = '<td>  '.$bname.'</td>';
```

Comment: i am still getting whole output .How to use it as array so that i only get books name.

Answer (score 1):

At the core of what you're asking is how to set a key-value pair:

```
$books = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  //get $bookName and $bookInformation

  //Save
  $books[$bookName] = $bookInformation;
}
```

Because you specify the key `$bookName`, anything else that has the same name will overwrite the key (`$bookName`) with the new value (`$bookInformation`). In php, if you use the construct:

```
$books[] = $bookInformation;
```

You will simply append `$bookInformation` to the end of the `$books` array.

Note that your code has a number of other issues. `$bname` is never defined, for instance, and you're mixing output (`echo`) with business logic (such as saving book names to an array). You should really separate these parts. Also note that you have at least one line that doesn't do anything:

```
'</br>';
```

Comment: thanx very much got the concept of []as i m beginner concepts are a little wavey for  me

Comment: Looking for just this one: `$books[$bookName] = $bookInformation;` - thanks a lot